# Is this a form of reduction?

Tags: phonology

What is it called in spoken English when a hard consonant at the end of a word 'pulls' the next word to it. For example: I don't like tea at all. --> 'I don't like tea uh tall."  The wind is strong. --> 'The win diz strong.'

Answer (score 3):

It's called "liaison", after the more systematic phenomenon in French, where consonants at the end of a word, which would ordinarily come at the end of a syllable, are pronounced as though they came at the beginning of a syllable whose vowel is the first sound of the following word.  Commonly, consonants at the beginning of a syllable are strongly articulated, i.e. "fortis", while consonants at the end of a syllble are weakly articulated, i.e. "lenis".

Using a period to stand for syllable boundary, in your example

```
I . don't . like . tea . at . all
```

through liaison becomes

```
I . don't . like . tea . a . tall
```

The "t" at the end of the "at" syllable, since it is between vowels, is ordinarily lenited in American English by making it into a voiced flap.  But after liaison, because it is now at the beginning of a syllable, "t" is fortified by making it aspirated instead.

A similar example in American English is pronouncing

```
this . evening
```

with lenis "s", as instead

```
thi . sevening
```

with fortis syllable-initial "s".  In this example, the change in syllabification also has consequences for the pronunciation of the vowel of "this", which is not reduced to schwa in the closed syllable of "this", but is reduced in the open syllable formed by liaison, making it sound like "the".